# Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected

Tags: devise

I have an issue though. I am following https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/authentication-with-angularjs-and-ruby-on-rails for my work.

Using ng-token-auth and devise_token_auth

In Controller

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:new, :create]
```

but all the API's calls are getting this error:

`Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected`

Any suggestions would help

Answer (score 0):

Ok Sure how about this instead?:

Change your call from @user to @current_user in after_token_authentication. You're authenticate_user! call requires @current_user

```
sign_in @current_user, :bypass => true
```

Comment: I want to get the current user and hence have to use authenticate_user!